# Since Java can run on the client-side using JVM, my professor says it is a client-side programming language also. Can somebody explain if he is right?

Tags: programming-languages, web

JavaScript and VBScript are both designed to run on client-side browsers from its original design, and they have long been recognized as "client-side scripting languages" (until NodeJS came out).

However, my professor argues that *Java* is also a client-side programming language, given that Java Applet runs directly on a browser with add-on. My arguments are that Java is not a client-side programming language as it was not designed for it. Also, it requires the JVM, it is not a native application language that can run directly on a browser. Although different languages can be altered to adapt similar functionalities, it does not mean they fit for the purposes.

We always hear terms like "client-side programming languages", but is there really a way to define it? Can somebody explain to me who is right please?

Comment: If it runs on the client, it's a client side programming language. Java can run on the client. Sure it takes special software (requires a plug-in), but so does JavaScript (requires a Web browser). You're trying to push an agenda that makes no sense.

Comment: @JoeWhite, may I have more of your opinions please? Or, would you write an answer please?

Comment: @hllau In my opinion, you reduce the meaning of "client" to the web browsers, which is not exact. I assume the client to be a machine controlled by a user, usually equipped with a GUI, so if the Java applet runs on it - despite the fact it requires a JVM - it is a client-side programming. The web browser is an application to improve the fruition of web contents on a machine, interpreting user's actions made through the GUI and sending them to the machine, which materially makes the HTTP request. Then it takes the response the machine receives and elaborates it to display to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit: This was the answer to the original unedited question that asked which of the languages are not client-side language. The answer doesn't seem much relevant after those edits)

[Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)

JavaScript and VBScript are both scripting languages that usually (not always) run in client web browser.

Just google them and you'll find why.

Answer to your comment:

Java Applets lets the java program run in the web browser, but that does not count as client side technology because to run the Java Applet, the client system must have Java Virtual Machine installed. It is much like downloading a compiled java program from a web site and running it on the client. JavaScript and VBScript are both run by the browser. These two languages are created for the client-side (but they have new usages in another environments). That is not the case with Java Applet.

Comment: Thank you. I would think Java is not the language also.

Comment: However, this question appears in an examination I just took and the professor asserts that Java is a client side language, as Java applet can be run on the client side. May I kindly have your opinion please?

Also, I am not sure who did the down vote. I am sincerely asking for help. Please adjust it.

Comment: @hllau: Java IS a programming language and a software platform.

Comment: Would you give me a concrete reason that I can show my professor Java is not a client side language? Thank you very much as your are an MD also.

I select "Java" for the question also, but my professor argues it is client-side. I need more support with people with credibility.

Comment: @hllau: Your professor could also assert that Java is not a client side language if you had selected option number 4! These concepts are not so concrete. These are just concepts.

Comment: But as a usual case and a common sense to active developers, language are designed for different purposes. When we are talking about client side language, it is clear that JavaScript and VBScript are specially designed to be run on the client browser from its originality, but Java is not designed for this purpose. Sure, languages can be used and adjusted to match different use case, but it does not mean they are the appropriate technology. May I have your point of view please?

Comment: @hllau: I agree with you. What you said is exactly what I have in mind. There are also server side technologies that use JavaScript ([node.js](http://nodejs.org)) or VBScript. JavaScript also is used in other environments ([MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) uses JavaScript as the query language). So **is** JavaScript a client side language or **is not**? This cannot be definitely answered.